# Qt error: "Cannot open output file debug\prog.exe: Permission denied"

Tags: qt

I'm developing in Qt 5.11.1/ Qt Creator 4.6.2, with the default compiler kit that came with QtInstaller, MinGW 5.3.0 32bit. My system is Windows 10 64bit.

After several runs without any error (months), I'm starting to get the following error sometimes:

```
Cannot open output file debug\prog.exe: Permission denied
error: ld returned 1 exit status
File not found: collect2.exe
```

I've already open the Task Manager to see if my program's still running but there isn't any entry there. And it appears to be a problem with the executable in the folder "debug", because after that, I'm not allowed to erase the prog.exe. The message box said I don't have the right permissions, but I'm the administrator user.

The problem only disappear if I restart Windows.

Here's my .pro code:

```
QT += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = prog
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    prog.cpp \
    screen1.cpp \
    screen2.cpp \

HEADERS += \
    defineBotoes.h \
    prog.h \
    screen1.h \
    screen2.h \

RESOURCES += \
    resources/prog.qrc

DISTFILES +=
```

And here's my Compile Output:

```
C:/Qt/Qt5.11.1/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file debug\prog.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Debug:100: recipe for target 'debug\prog.exe' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/RENAN-BCC/Desktop/STD/src/prog'
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'debug' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\prog.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
08:31:49: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.11.1\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project prog (kit: Desktop Qt 5.11.1 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
08:31:49: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

Can someone help me? Any idea about how to solve?

Comment: Does a clean build solve the problem? Or removing the build folder?

Comment: No. I've followed the steps: Clean All >> Run QMake >> Build All >> Run, and the problem continues.

And I'm not allowed to remove the debug folder. I don't have the right permissions.

Comment: And removing the build folder in the explorer? This works sometimes better than clean all.

Comment: With this problem, I'm not allowed to delete the executable prog.exe anymore. Consequently, the build/debug folder is locked too.

Comment: You can try to check which program is locking the file using one of the methods mentioned in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows).

Comment: Reboot. That’s all.